# RAM RGB not changing on 1 stick after RAM upgrade

Tags: memory, drivers, motherboard, rgb

My MSI PRO B760-P WIFI has 2 Kingston Fury RGB DDR5 sticks and the RGB is working properly. I added 2 non-RGB sticks of the same speed, brand, just not RGB. Now, after rebooting, during startup, colors cycle properly until windows starts. Then, one of the sticks stays the same color after startup. The other stick responds properly to RGB control.
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using any software to control the RGB, or is it done through the BIOS? If the former, does it show the RAM sticks where you set the colours?

Comment: Have you removed and reseated the RAM?

Comment: @AndrewMorton - Using MSI Mystic Light. It recognizes the ram. 1 stick does what it's supposed to, the other locks at the color in is at when the driver loads (when windows loads, even prior to login.

Comment: @Mokubai - Yes, just reseated all of it. Same thing.

Comment: @asp316 Have you tried swapping the RAM around? Maybe the software tries to do all the RAM sticks in some order, and when it doesn't get a response from one of them it stops going through the sticks.

Comment: @AndrewMorton That did it! Thanks! Sticks had to be at the front of the bank together. Please put it as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only supposition, but if the lighting software tries to do all the RAM sticks in some order, and when it doesn't get a response from one of them it stops going through the sticks, then you may be able to make both RGB RAM sticks work by placing them in different slots.